# Store Image in object

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to store an image in an object in python. My Constructor is

```
from PIL import Image

class MyImage:
    def __init__(self, ImageFileName):

        self.ImageFileName = ImageFileName

        self.Img=Image.open(ImageFileName)#.convert("1")
        Image._show(self.Img) #this shows the image
```

but when I call this outside the class in a different file

```
myObject = MyImage('FileName')
Image._show(myObject.Img)#this does not show the image
```

I am new to python but I can't figure out what is wrong. 
Thanks.

Comment: Please make a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Seems to work for me. "does not show the image" is a bit too vague. Do you get any error messages?